# Parent object reference

Tags: javascript, object

I think I may  be missing something coming to object reference, in the below case, is `this` refering to the test object? If not how can I declare `b` so in the end `test.a = test.b` ?

```
test = {
 a: 1,
 b: this.a,
 check : function(){
  console.log(test.a); // returns 1
  console.log(test.b); // returns undefined
 }
};
test.check();
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare it like this:

```
function test(){
   this.a = 1;
   this.b = this.a;

    this.check = function(){
       console.log(this.a);  // output 1
       console.log(this.b); // output 1
    }        
}

var t = new test();
t.check();
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Rqs86/

Comment: new is keyword here. You need to create a new instance of test constructor in order to get desired output.

Comment: So if i get it correctly, you can not reference an object property declared within the same object scope level. I take this for solution, even if not, and Thank you for the demo aswell :)

Answer (score 2):

`test.b` refers to whatever `this.a` was when declaring the object.

```
var foo = this;
```

You wouldn't expect `this` to refer to `foo` here, right? It works exactly the same here:

```
var bar = [ this ];
```

and

```
var baz = { 'blag' : this };
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful to understand why this refers to nuts when b is declared. But then, how can i get b to build itself on top of a, basically a is a jquery object, and b is a property of this object. a: $('.class'), b:a.css() for example.

Comment: See @Jamiec's answer. Use a function which evaluates `this` at call time, not at declaration time.

Comment: Working too much with jquery the difference between declaration time and call time can seem blurry ;)